# How can I search for values in a .txt file in python?

Tags: python

I just need a little help with my code.  I ask for name input and I try to make the code check if the input is in the user, but it always says that it's the user's first time.

```
name_file = open("NAME_DATA.txt", "r")

name = str(input("Hello, What is your first and last name?\n"))


if name in name_file:
  Clear()
  print("Good to see you again! It looks like you have used this before!")
  tm.sleep(3)
  name_file.close()
if name not in name_file:
  Clear()
  print("I see this is your first time using this software. Have fun!  Just a disclaimer, your 
  name will be added to the name_data.txt file, but we will never share anyones name!")
  tm.sleep(5)
  name_file = open("NAME_DATA.txt", "a")
  name_file.write(str(name) + "\n")
  name_file.close()
```

Please somebody help me with this!!

Comment: if you want to check if `name` exists in the *contents* of the file, you've to read it in a variable and then check if `name` exists in that. `name in name_file` just checks if `name` exists in the file object itself, not the file contents

Comment: Thanks so much it worked!! I'm new to this so thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the text file.

Try this code:

```
name_file = open("NAME_DATA.txt", "r")
data = name_file.read()

name = str(input("Hello, What is your first and last name?\n"))
    
if name in data:
  Clear()
  print("Good to see you again! It looks like you have used this before!")
  tm.sleep(3)
  name_file.close()
else:  #if not name in data:
  Clear()
  print("I see this is your first time using this software. Have fun!  Just a disclaimer, your 
  name will be added to the name_data.txt file, but we will never share anyones name!")
  tm.sleep(5)
  name_file = open("NAME_DATA.txt", "a")
  name_file.write(str(name) + "\n")
  name_file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Mike67 said in the comments before I could:

```
name_file = open("NAME_DATA.txt", "r").read()
```

Will read the file as text (string)

you can also use `.readlines()` to make a list from each line in the txt files for further processing

Answer (score 0):

You should really consider using the `with` context manager when working with files, this way you do not need to worry about opening and closing file handles. Additionally I would be surprised if you do not get an error on the conditional block `name not in name_file` given you open the file with a different mode before closing it again. I would do something more like this

```py
with open("NAME_DATA.txt", "r") as name_file:
    data = name_file.read()

name = str(input("Hello, What is your first and last name?\n"))

if name in data:
    Clear()
    print("Good to see you again! It looks like you have used this before!")
    tm.sleep(3)
else:
    Clear()
    print("I see this is your first time using this software. Have fun!  Just a disclaimer, your 
  name will be added to the name_data.txt file, but we will never share anyones name!")
    tm.sleep(5)
    with open("NAME_DATA.txt", "a") as name_file:
        name_file.write(str(name) + "\n")
```